# Strange error with template literal adding *{} to string

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit, template-literals

I am facing a weird error where copying svelte code into a template literal is adding `*{}` to the string. I tried replicating this in a REPL to share, but the error didn't occur there. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

**Example:**
`+page.svelte`

```js
  let svelteCode = `
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte'
<\/script>

<p>These styles...</p>
<Nested/>

<style>
    p {
        color: purple;
        font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>`;

    $: console.log('-----svelteCode:', svelteCode);
```

**Result of `console.log()`:**

```
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte'
</script>

<p>These styles...</p>
<Nested/>

<style>
    p {
        color: purple;
        font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
 *{}</style>
```

In the last line `*{}` was added for some reason and I can't figure out where it's coming from, since I'm just printing the string without making any adjustments to it.

When I remove the `<style>...</style>` block the `*{}` disappears or when I just remove `style` from the `<>` tags, but I can't figure out why this happens. I'm a bit lost. Any ideas on what is causing this?

I expect the string output to be the same as the defined string.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @B45i I've added a screenshot of my Firefox console now.

Comment: It might just be Firefox showing it for some reason. Does it appear in the page source?

Comment: @isherwood it also appears in Chrome I just checked. When I display it on the website either as a string or with `{@html svelteCode}` it also appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser [has issues with tags](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5292) in code. I cannot tell why it specifically generates `*{}` but I would recommend doing something like `</${''}style>` or `<\/style>` to work around the problem.

Comment: This solved it for me. Another option someone found was to import the string from a separate `.js` file, but this is a bit nicer. Thank you!